# How to override url params with rewrite rules vars?

Tags: php, wordpress, parameters, url-rewriting

**Setup a rule:**

```
add_action( 'init',  function() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^myparamname/?$', 'index.php?myparamname=hello', 'top' );
} );
```

**Whitelist the query param:**

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'myparamname';
    return $query_vars;
} );
```

**Get query vars:**

`localhost/myparamname`

```
get_query_var('myparamname'); // hello
```

`localhost/myparamname?myparamname=hi` or
`localhost/myparamname/?myparamname=hi`

```
get_query_var('myparamname'); // hi
```

As you can see, **"hi"** message is displayed instead of **"hello"** in the second example. Here, the desired situation is generally **"hello"**.